# Find Available IP to host port

Tags: php, tcp

Im having a headache trying to figure out how to find an IP address in my list with the available ports.
My problem is quite simple actually but I just can't figure out how to program it.
I was hopping someone can point me in the right direction.
Maybe there is a way to optimize the list for it to be easier to search in it.

Any how here is my problem.
I have a list of IP and multiple ports on each of them own by a client.
I can have multiple clients on the same IP, but i can't have a client on multiple IP

So im trying to build a function that would tell me "hey you need to switch this client on this ip so you can have x client on this ip
So here is my example list.

```
$ReservedPortsOnIPs = array(
    '10.0.0.1'=>array(
        'TCP:80'=>array(
            'ClientId'=>1
        ),
        'TCP:443'=>array(
            'ClientId'=>1
        )
    ),
    '10.0.0.2'=>array(
        'TCP:80'=>array(
            'ClientId'=>2
        )
    ),
    '10.0.0.3'=>array(
        'TCP:443'=>array(
            'ClientId'=>4
        ),
        'TCP:22'=>array(
            'ClientId'=>4
        ),
    )
);
```

Now here is my code I have til now. ( im only able to find available IP ) so at the moment if for example im trying to find an ip available with lets say `TCP:80` and `TCP:443`
There is none directly available but if I would change cleint 4 from `10.0.0.3` to `10.0.0.2` I would have `10.0.0.3` avaible for the ports im asking.

Im at a point where I need to do the same task but recursively but I have no idea how start ? :S

```
function PortAvailableInNetwork($Port, $ReservedPortsOnIPs){
    foreach($ReservedPortsOnIPs as $IP => $Ports) {
        if(!isset($Ports[$Port]))
            return true; //We found it not used!
    }
    return false; // foreach runned and no ip has the port available.
}
function AddPort($Ports,$ClientId,&$ReservedPortsOnIPs)
{
    //check if ports possibly available
    if(!is_array($Ports))
    {
        if(!PortAvailableInNetwork($Ports,$ReservedPortsOnIPs))
            return false;
    }
    else
        foreach($Ports as $Port)
            if(!PortAvailableInNetwork($Port,$ReservedPortsOnIPs))
                return false;

    $TmpReservedPortOnIp = $ReservedPortsOnIPs;
    //Find Current Ports ClientId Has
    $ClientsPorts = array();
    if(!is_array($Ports))
        $ClientsPorts[] = $Ports;
    else
        foreach($Ports as $Port)
            $ClientsPorts[] = $Port;
    foreach($ReservedPortsOnIPs as $IP => $Ports){
        foreach($Ports as $Port => $PortInfo){
            if($PortInfo['ClientId'] == $ClientId)
            {
                $ClientsPorts[] = $Port;
                unset($TmpReservedPortOnIp[$IP][$Port]); //Remove the clientPort for search purposes
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($ClientsPorts);
    //Now that we have all client ports lets search for an available ip address
    $PortsAvailability = array();
    foreach($TmpReservedPortOnIp as $IP => $Ports){
        $PortsAvailability[$IP] = array('Available'=>array(),'UnAvailable'=>array());
        foreach($ClientsPorts as $Port){
            if(!isset($Ports[$Port]))
                $PortsAvailability[$IP]['Available'][]=$Port;
            else
                $PortsAvailability[$IP]['UnAvailable'][]=$Port;
        }
        if(count($PortsAvailability[$IP]['Available']) == count($ClientsPorts))
            return $IP;
    }
    //if we are at this step this mean no ip had all ports
    usort($PortsAvailability,function($a,$b){
        if(count($a['Available']) > count($b['Available']))
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    });
    print_r($PortsAvailability);
}
echo AddPort(array('TCP:80','TCP:443'),5,$ReservedPortsOnIPs);
```

I am open to change my design, as I did this on top of my head the way I could see the problem and its maybe not the right way to do it.

thanks for your time reading my question :)

Comment: Re: "if I would change client 4 from 10.0.0.3 to 10.0.0.2 I would have 10.0.0.3 avaible for the ports im asking.", but then what would you do with client #2?

Comment: They both can be on `10.0.0.2` since they don't need the sames ports client 2 need `tcp:80` and client 4 `tcp:22,tcp:443`
Or both client 2 and 4 could be on `10.0.0.3` it doesn't really mater. what mater is no client can have the same port on one ip

Comment: Ah, I see - but what if client #4 needed 80 also, then what?

Comment: Then the function would need to return false or imposible to add port request or something like that.
But i could give 80 to client 4
But the new client 5 can't have 80 and 443

Comment: Makes sense. So is your question more in regards on how to automatically balance out the clients to the right ip/ports through `PHP` — and how are you doing this currently (if so)?

Comment: Well,. my question is how can I do the function recursively so I can take ports from an other client and kinda move them around so i can find a ip programmaticly, or perhaps if someone see a different approach ( which i don't see at the moment )
And at the moment i don't but I build a backend to send commands to routers on my infrastructure to change multiple things I just never programmaticly nat-ed stuff before, But this is what im looking to do.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways you could set this up, and I think you're not that far off from having something usable to start with. One suggestion would be to not include the `ClientId` association for a port that is `Available` — since the port is already associated with the IP. The "unavailable" aspect seems to be the important part from what you've mentioned, so if a client isn't using a certain port on a certain IP you already know it's available right?

Comment: yeah,. You are completely right. But client id come handy when i need to try moving it around since I can't have multiple ip for one client, So at that point I need to check what other port is own by that client and try those ports in other IPs if it fits in there.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted your array in that case, thinking that any client listed under an IP was using whatever ports where specified (eg. `10.0.0.1`, `ClientId 1`, using ports `80, 443`)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123302/discussion-between-nicolas-racine-and-lll).